# Twitter API not working in loop

Tags: php, twitter

I am using the api below to populate the loop below which works perfecly

```
 $tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q='.$queryString.'&count=400');

 <?php foreach ($tweets->statuses as $key => $tweet) { ?>
 <?=$tweet->name; ?><br/>
 <img src="<?=$tweet->user->profile_image_url;?>" />
 <?=$tweet->text; ?>
```

I then changed the API to

```
$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?q='.$queryString.'&count=400');
```

but keep to getting this error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

I think i have make a few changes to the foreach but i have no idea what to change.

Thanks you.

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($tweets)` on the `home_timeline` request to see what the return looks like. `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` means that the variable `$tweets->statuses` isn't an array that `foreach` can loop over.

Comment: Actually, the `home_timeline` result will return a set of tweets, so there's no `statuses` object. Take a look at this page, especially the example result: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/home_timeline

Comment: @JakeB. Thanks, I have had a read through and i understant why its not working. Please how else can i loop the result?

Comment: I'll post a full answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over the results of the `home_timeline` request, try this (untested):

```
$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=400');

 <?php foreach ($tweets as $key => $tweet) { ?>
 <?=$tweet->user->name; ?><br/>
 <img src="<?=$tweet->user->profile_image_url;?>" />
 <?=$tweet->text; ?>
```

I also changed the API URL for `home_timeline`, because it doesn't take a query string (same documentation link that I posted). Instead, it will pull the timeline for the currently authenticated user.